# How do I change sheetname and the filename using xlwings?

Tags: python, xlwings

```
wb_cover = xw.Book()
wb_table = xw.Book()            
wb1 = xw.Book(path1)
ws1 = wb1.sheets("Table")
ws2 = wb1.sheets("Cover")

ws1.api.Copy(Before=wb_table.sheets(1).api)
ws2.api.Copy(Before=wb_cover.sheets(1).api)
```

When the sheet gets copied it keeps the same name also on the new file. Is there the possibility to rename the sheets?